# How to treat missing id 's value as 0 and order by it?

Tags: mysql, sql

When I use `in` keyword in sql, there may be some id is missing , but I want treat them like they exist and other columns are null or 0.

For example, suppose I have a table with two columns and some rows:
[id,value1]
1        1
2        4
3        3
5        5

I may write sql like this:
`select * from table where id in (1,4,5) order by value1 limit 0,2 ;`
When this sql is executed, the return result is [(1,1),(5,5)].
But what I want is [(4,0),(1,1)], because I want to treat the missing id 4 like it exists in the table.

So the question is : Is there some elegant way to achieve it using sql instead of select all rows and sort them in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `left join`:

```
select *
from (select 1 as id union all
      select 4 union all
      select 5
     ) i left join
     table t
     using (id)
order by t.value1
limit 0, 2 ;
```

Note that you are ordering by a value in the existing table, so this depends on the fact that `NULL` is ordered before other values.